# Create package from existing git repo

Tags: php, git, composer-php, packagist

I have a situation like this... I am working on a project that at some point got bigger than I thought it would be. This is project contains basically 2 important parts that work together but I want to separate them.

the first part contains this structure:

```
-- app
---- templates
------- compiled
------- form-template-files
--------- [some-files]
---- Formbuilder
------- Handlers
--------- Default.php
--------- DGSD.php
------- HandlerInterface.php
------- FormBuilder.php
-- public
---- [some client files]
---- index.php
-- vendor
```

This project grew and now I wish to separate `FormBuilder` directory from the app, into a new repository so I can add it into the packagist so after I could include `FormBuilder` as a package using composer

The question is how I do this? How to grab the folder with related commits and move them into a new repository, so I could later use this as a package?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/q/359424/367456)